# How to remove edges from eliptical tool selection?

Tags: gimp, crop

You cannot see it when it's on a white background, but Can someone tell me how I can erase the boarder from this image in Gimp? I want it to be a perfect circle. I'm going to be using this with a colored background.

[image]

Comment: Maybe it would help if you posted this image with a background that wasn't white?

Comment: Well you make a good point.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I used the fuzzy selection tool, set the threshold to 0 then selected the whit background. After that you simply create an alpha channel and delete.

Anyone else know another way?

Comment: Try also to [feather](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-selection-feather.html) the selection.

Comment: Hey thank you, that is a great idea. My edges came out very rough. I will try this approach.